# Counting Subqueries

Tags: sql

My last quest was too vague, so I will revise it.  I know the following isn't correct SQL syntax, however you should be able to get the gist of the query I'm trying to perform.

```
select id, 
       title, 
       count(select x 
              from otherTable 
             where otherTable.id = thisTable.id) as new_row 
 from thisTable
```

I hope this is a bit better explained.

Comment: @Camony : If there are no matching rows in outer table then still do you want to show 0 as count? in this case inner join wont work i think...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select tt.id, tt.title, count(ot.id) as count
from thisTable tt
inner join otherTable ot on ot.id = tt.id
group by tt.id, tt.title
```

Comment: easier to fix than be offended.

Comment: @Evan Carroll: Zee brackets, zay do nuTHING! :) +1

Comment: hey guys may I still touch my own answer? ))

Comment: A left join instead of an inner join would show thisTable records with no matching otherTable records.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution. If you want to know the row count, and not the number of distinct x values, then use count(*) instead of count(distinct x).

```
select id, title,
    (select count(distinct x) from otherTable
    where otherTable.id = thisTable.id) as new_row 
from thisTable
```